# What to do when a new user leaves a comment as an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

A new user apparently wanted to comment on an answer ([link](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/5468/1749)), but didn't have enough rep so just submitted it as another answer. I'd like give the user a warmer welcome than flagging the non-answer for deletion, can it somehow be migrated into a comment while maintaining their ownership or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators can convert answers to comments, so flagging is the correct way to do that. You could additionally leave a nice comment explaining how this site is different and that you shouldn't post comments as answers.

Comment: This is correct, note that the answer getting deleted is another possible outcome if the moderator feels it isn't adding much to the conversation.

Comment: Saying that you shouldn't post comments as answers to somebody who's not allowed to post comments seems a little off.  Why is the comment threshold higher than the answer threshold, and should we be addressing that?

Comment: @Monica Raising the threshold for answers doesn't make sense, answering is how most users get their first rep.  Lowering it to 1 for comments also doesn't make sense, it would cause a huge influx of spam comments.  So just acknowledge that they can't make the comment on their own, but that it shouldn't be an answer, so a mod will convert it for them.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - This isn't a forum and commenting is a privilege earned by participating in the community rather than granted to everyone who happens by.

Comment: Gotcha.  I asked the question (in a comment :-) ) because it's a question, not an opinion.  Comments seemed "less" than answers so I wondered at the higher bar, but I hadn't considered the spam angle.